# Why do a add_index migration add the type string to a column if not called otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2, migration

I have a table with an already existant `t.integer :column_name`.

If i do a  `rails g migration add_index_to_table_name column_name:uniq` the already existent column_name will created new with a string type if I dont call it otherwise with `column_name:integer:uniq`

Why is this? Wouldnt it be easier to just add the index `:unique => true` to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper method is only intended to handle adding or removing columns: [API Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) and [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration).

You will need to first generate the migration:

```
rails g migration add_index_to_table_name
```

and then edit it to contain the appropriate commands:

```
class AddIndexToTableName < ActiveRecord:Migration
  def change
    add_index :table_name, :column_name, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: ah so the add_index command will be generated from the `:uniq` and not from the `add_index_to_table`

Comment: I played around with this a bit more - it looks like the :uniq is designed to be used when the column is created, not to modify it later. So even in your use case of `column_name:integer:uniq` it will try to re-add the column and the migration will fail.